# group pandas DataFrame by one column and then get lists of values which occur in those categories from other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am looking for a possibility to group a DataFrame by one (or more) columns and than add another column to the grouped DataFrame which gives me those values that occure in this categorie from another column in the original DataFrame. (It's probably easier understand what I would like to do by the follwing example.)

For example I have a DataFrame which contains the information of the color and location of some cars. I want to know how many cars of each color I have (for this I use groupby, but I am open for other suggestions), but I would also like to get a list of cities those cars are located in.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'cars': ['A','B','C', 'D', 'E'], 'color':['blue','red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue'], 'city':['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Z', 'Z']})

df =
  cars city color
0    A    X  blue
1    B    Y   red
2    C    X  blue
3    D    Z   red
4    E    Z  blue

new_df = df.groupby(['color']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'nr_of_cars'})

new_df = 
  color  nr_of_cars
0  blue           3
1   red           2
```

So in my_df I have the number of cars whith each color, but I would also like to know the cities those cars are located in. A new DataFrame would finally look like this (I don't exactly need those cities in the same DataFrame, I just need to accees them easily):

```
  color  nr_of_cars     cities
0  blue           3      X, Z
1   red           2      Y, Z
```

What I know is that I could do a conditional selection for each color.

```
other_df = df[df['color'] == 'blue']['city'].unique()
```

But is there a way where I do not have to loop through a list of colors? My real DataFrame is a bit bigger, so that I would be happy to receive some suggestions.

edit: Just fixed typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [90]: df.groupby('color').agg({'cars':'size','city':'unique'}).reset_index()
Out[90]:
  color  cars    city
0  blue     3  [X, Z]
1   red     2  [Y, Z]
```

@Dillon,

if you want to see all available aggregate methods (functions) and attributes, then try to use `ipython` or `Jupyter` like as follows:

first create a "GroupBy" object:

```
In [91]: g = df.groupby('color')
```

then type `g.` and press `<Tab>` key:

```
In [92]: g.
    g.agg        g.apply      g.cars       g.corrwith   g.cummax     g.describe   g.ffill      g.get_group  g.idxmax     g.mad        g.min
    g.aggregate  g.backfill   g.city       g.count      g.cummin     g.diff       g.fillna     g.groups     g.idxmin     g.max        g.ndim
    g.all        g.bfill      g.color      g.cov        g.cumprod    g.dtypes     g.filter     g.head       g.indices    g.mean       g.ngroup     >
    g.any        g.boxplot    g.corr       g.cumcount   g.cumsum     g.expanding  g.first      g.hist       g.last       g.median     g.ngroup
```

Comment: Do you know where can I find a list of all the pandas aggregation types?

Comment: @Dillon, do you mean aggregation functions?

Comment: Yes 'functions' not types

Comment: @Dillon, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id39. If you want to see a full list of available methods and attributes, then follow an instruction in the answer...

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I wasn't aware of this function yet.

Comment: @iClarinha, glad i could help :)